# Big-O notation in nested loops

Tags: big-o

What is the Big-Oh formula for the following code fragment:

```
k=0

for i in range(1,100) :

   for j in range(i, 100) :

        k = k + 1
```

I think its n^2? Is this right? Also does it have to have the n variable in it?

Comment: There is no `n` in the code, neither any other variable input, so it's `O(1)`.

Comment: The code is completely independent from any input, so it is `O(1)`.

Comment: FWIW: `n` in Big-O is independent of any variable named "n" in the actual code. It is the de facto convention used in the notation (but is not the only variable that can appear, when qualified).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithmic complexity of code isn't determined by its time to run. It determined by how much extra work a computer has to do depending on the input.

This code has **O(1)** as regardless of any input you give it it does the exact same thing in the same amount of time

```
k = 0
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        k+=1
```

This code however would have **O(N)** time if N is a number given as input because each increment of N makes it do 1 more think

```
k = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(100):
        k+=1
```

And *this* code however would have **O(N^2)** time if N is a number given as input because each increment of N makes the computer do N more things

```
k = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(100):
        k+=1
```

So you code has **O(1)** as it does the same amount of "Things" regardless of any input